# jquery ui tabs wrong position value of inactive tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a trouble with element positions of inactive tab.

HTML:

```
    <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1">
                <p id="t1">text 1</p>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-2">
                <p id="t2">text 3</p>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-3">
                <p id="t3">text 3</p>
            </div>
        </div>
<input type="button" value="getPosition"  onclick="getP();"/>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({active: 0});

    // set position
    $('#t1').css('position', 'absolute');
    $('#t2').css('position', 'absolute');
    $('#t3').css('position', 'absolute');

    // set top
    $('#t1').css('top', '50px');
    $('#t2').css('top', '70px');
    $('#t3').css('top', '90px');

    // set left
    $('#t1').css('left', '100px');
    $('#t2').css('left', '200px');
    $('#t3').css('left', '300px');

});

function getP() {
    var pos1 = $('#t1').position();
    var pos2 = $('#t2').position();
    var pos3 = $('#t3').position();

    alert('t1: top='+pos1.top+' left='+pos1.left+' t2: top='+pos2.top+' left='+pos2.left+' t3: top='+pos3.top+' left='+pos3.left);
}
```

Live:
http://jsfiddle.net/xnmHj/

I understand that because of jq ui works, but I need to get right parameters and tired to find solution, or maybe just I'm blind . I will be happy for any info. 
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inactive tabs are set to `display:none`.

You can get coordinates of `visibility:hidden` elements, but `display:none` elements are excluded from rendering tree. So their position is undefined.

You can get the css styles inline data, if they are helpful.

Alternatively you can set the element visible, get its position and then hide it again, but can cause rendering issues.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/xnmHj/1/